# QGIS. Polygon vertices automatic bind to WFS point features

Tags: qgis, wfs, vertices, databinding

I have a layer with polygons in QGIS.
I have a layer in the same project with points from a WFS.

Is it possible to bind vertices from a polygon to points from the WFS layer. So if the admin of the WFS updates a position of a point, the polygon automaticly changes the bound vertices to the new position of the points?

Comment: Do you need the polygon as a layer, or only for display? It might be possible with a geometry generator style.

Comment: Yes, because I use the polygon layer as a referencelayer in my system by using geomwithin